# Why my binary to decimal conversion is not working in java?

Tags: java, methods, binary, decimal

I have this method where it converts a binary input from a user to decimal value.

Main Method:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
String inputByUserString=""; //number input by the player
int inputByUserInteger;
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number"); //getting the input
inputByUserString=sc.nextLine();
inputByUserInteger=Integer.parseInt(inputByUserString);
```

and then I create a switch case where there is more options for conversion like Decimal number to Binary number etc...

Then in that switch I call a method:

```
    int binaryToDecimalNumberVariable=obj1.binaryToDecimalConversion(inputByUserInteger);   
    System.out.println("Binary Number:"+inputByUserInteger);
    System.out.println("Decimal Number:"+binaryToDecimalNumberVariable);
```

Method for binary to decimal conversion:

```
public int binaryToDecimalConversion(int inp) //to convert binary number into decimal number
{
int a1;int a2=0;int a3 = 0;
while(inp>0)
{
    a1=inp%10;
    a1=inp/10;
    a3=(int)(a3+(a1*(Math.pow(2,a2)))); //result
    a2++;   
}
return a3;
}
```

The whole switch case:

```
  System.out.println("What type of conversion do you want?");
  System.out.println("1)Decimal number to Binary number");
  System.out.println("2)Binary number to Decimal number");
  System.out.println("3)Decimal number to Octal number");
  System.out.println("4)Octal number to Decimal number");
  System.out.println("5)Decimal number to Hexadecimal number");
  System.out.println("6)Hexadecimal number to Decimal number");
  System.out.println("7)Octal number to Hexadecimal number");
  System.out.println("8)Hexadecimal number to Octal number");
  int choice=sc.nextInt();
  switch(choice)
  {
  case 1: //Decimal number to Binary number
  break;
  case 2: //Binary number to Decimal number
    int binaryToDeci=obj1.binaryToDecimalConversion(inputByUserInteger);    
    System.out.println("Binary Number:"+inputByUserInteger);
    System.out.println("Decimal Number:"+binaryToDeci);
break;
case 3: //Decimal number to Octal number
break;
case 4: //Octal number to Decimal number
break;
case 5: //Decimal number to Hexadecimal number
break;
case 6: //Hexadecimal number to Decimal number
break;
case 7: //Octal number to Hexadecimal number
break;
case 8: //Hexadecimal number to Octal number
break;
default:
System.out.println("Invalid Input");
} //switch close
```

It shows no error while compiling but when I execute it,it just stucks.

Error that is showing when I execute it:

[image]

So, help me.

Comment: Did you remember to use `break;` in your cases? Can you show the whole switch-case block? Also, Instead of `nextLine()`, why don't you use `nextInt()` ? Then you don't need conversion.

Comment: Have you tried debugging or just inserting some `System.out.println()` to see if the methods are being invoked correctly, if the switch-case is working, etc?

Comment: Why are you trying to convert the int from binary to decimal?  That makes no sense.  int itself doesn't have a radix.  The string form has a radix, so perform the conversion when converting from string to int, and int to string.

Comment: At any point, did you close sc like this: `sc.close()`? If you have, that may be the cause of your problem.

Comment: No, that's not the problem.  There's an obvious infinite loop in the binaryToDecimalConversion method.  However, the method really isn't needed.  Look at my answer and delete that conversion method and it will be problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, the correct way to handle your requirements:

```
String myBinaryNr = sc.next();
int myNr = Integer.parseInt(myBinaryNr, 2);
String myDecimalNr = Integer.toString(myNr, 10);
```

The last 10 is optional, since it is the default.

Answer (score 0):

If it's getting stuck, it probably hasn't detected an input and it's awaiting for it. To confirm this, I would add a

```
System.out.println("Test" + choice);
```

just under the choice input, so it would be like this:

```
int choice = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Test" + choice);
switch(choice){...}
```

If it doesn't print correctly, then you have found your issue. It may have something to do with the `System.in`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind,I just have to do this and it solves the problem.

```
public int binaryToDecimalConversion(int inp) //to convert binary number into decimal 
{
int a1;int a2=0;int a3 = 0;
while(inp>0)
{
a1=inp%10;
a3=(int)(a3+(a1*(Math.pow(2,a2)))); //result
a2++;   
inp=inp/10;
}
return a3;
}
```